# Unity - How do you detect screen tap on object in Unity 2D mobile game development in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oop, mobile, collision

I'm developing a 2D mobile game in Unity and I'm trying to detect whether a player's current finger tap position is on an Object.

Basically I am developing a game similiar to Insaniquarium Deluxe by PopCap games where you can spawn fish every time you tap on a button in exchange for in-game currency. Here's how the game looks.

[Game picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2wXS.png)

There's a button on the upper-left side of the screen where if you click on it, another fish would spawn in to the aquarium.

I'm trying to recreate this for a mobile game and I'm stuck trying to figure out the way to trace where the user clicks. I've come up with something that works if you tap anywhere on the screen and not just the button.

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Vector2 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                Collider2D touchedCollider = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(selectionEffect.transform.position);
                Debug.Log(touchPosition.x);

                if (col == touchedCollider)
                {
                    spawnFish();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What's the code to detect a tap on a Game Object?

Answer (score 0):

You should use unity's UI system for button creation as  it will automatically handle being interacted with, then you would simply assign the code you want to execute to that button.

here's a video to help introduce you to unity's UI system

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RIsfVOqTaE